# getting 'list object not callable" in keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to build a sequential model as follows, but on running, it is showing list object not callable on tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
          loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(training_images,  training_labels, batch_size=32),
                          steps_per_epoch=len(training_images) / 32,
                          epochs=15,
validation_data=validation_datagen.flow(testing_images, testing_labels, batch_size=32),
                          validation_steps=len(testing_images) / 32)

model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels)
```

The error which I am grtting on running the call is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a8af9687e7f3> in <module>
      6     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      7     tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
----> 8     tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
      9 ])
     10 



TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I couldn't find any error , Thanks in advance

Comment: The code is working fine for me. You should paste the whole traceback, the error is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seems to be  problem with the list that you're passing, neither with the model.

This error often occurs when you set the name of a variable as an existing module name, in your case you probably wrote `list = [...]` or something like that before building this model

Answer (score 0):

It has an issue with the training images and training labels checking the ndim or shape.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34834143)